# JSON Formatting Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to populate an html table of JSON data. I was provided the JSON data and cannot determine why it isn't populating but suspect the JSON may not be formatted properly. When I use other sample data it works, then when I sub in the JSON I was provided it doesn't work. I've tried copying the JSON into a file on my direct server, linking to what I was provided (here: https://boiling-fortress-75456.herokuapp.com/) and inserting it on myjson.com and reformatting the JSON data.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

      var entries = [];
      var dmJSON = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/6sjud?callback=?";
      $.getJSON(dmJSON, function(data) {
        $.each(data.entries, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.rank + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.march_rank + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.april_rank + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.may_rank + "</td>" + f.personal_volume + "</td>" + f.team_volume + "</td>" + "</tr>"
          $(tblRow).appendTo("#incentive tbody");
        });
      });
    });
    </script>


    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="profile">
        <table id= "incentive" border="1">
          <thead>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>March</th>
            <th>April</th>
            <th>May</th>
            <th>Highest Rank</th>
            <th>Personal Volume</th>
            <th>Team Volume</th>
          </thead>
        <tbody>

     </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The JSON coming back from that URL in your code has no property `entries`.

Comment: Note: *then when I sub in the JSON I was provided it doesn't work*. "Doesn't work" isn't a very useful description on the problem. What happens? Do you get an error message? What error message? Does it just not do what you expected? What did you expect and how does what actually happens differ.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the objects from `affiliate`

```
$.each(data.affiliate, function(i, f) {
    var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.rank + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.march_rank + "</td>" + "<td> " + f.april_rank + "</td>" +  "<td>" + f.may_rank + "</td>" + f.personal_volume + "</td>" + f.team_volume + "</td>" + "</tr>"
    $(tblRow).appendTo("#incentive tbody");
});
```

**Response from service**

```
{
    "affiliate":[{          
            "rank":1,"name":"Sally","march_rank":"Gold","april_rank":"Silver","may_rank":"Silver","highest_rank":"Silver","team_volume":12345
        },{
            "rank":2,"name":"Zelda","march_rank":"Gold","april_rank":"Bronze","may_rank":"Silver","highest_rank":"Gold","team_volume":12345
        }
    ]
}
```